# Prove that in the ring of integers of a number field: a non-zero ideal coprime to $c\in\mathbb{Z_{\geq1}}$ has norm coprime to $c$

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a non-zero ideal of the RoI of a number field  $A$, to say it is coprime to $c\in\mathbb{Z_{\geq1}}$ means: $\mathfrak{a}+cA=A$. The norm of $\mathfrak{a}$, or $N\mathfrak{a}$, is defined to be $|A/\mathfrak{a}|$ which can be shown to be finite.

I was able to prove the converse statement, that if $N\mathfrak{a}$ is coprime to $c$ then $\mathfrak{a}+cA=A$. This can be done via proving first that the multiplication by $c$ map from $A/\mathfrak{a}$ to itself is injective but then (as the set is finite) the map is surjective. This gives the result.

Thoughts on my question: 
Assume for contradiction that $c=pr$ and $N\mathfrak{a}=ps$ some $p$ prime then it was quite straightforward to show that $s\in \mathfrak{a}\cap\mathbb{Z}$, thus in particular every element of $A/\mathfrak{a}$ has order dividing $s$. I feel this ought to force some easy contradiction but I wasn't able to get it.

Comment: Can you work backwards? Doesn't $\mathfrak{a}+cA=A$ imply that multiplication by $c$ is a surjective endomorphism of the abelian group $B=A/\mathfrak{a}$, hence also injective. But $B$ is finite, so a direct sum of cyclic groups. For multiplication by $c$ to be injective in such a direct sum, none of the factors can have order not coprime to $c$.

Comment: Thank you! You're absolutely right, I did think of using the structure theorem but tried to use that _after_ what I wrote at the end of the post and that doesn't actually work.  I'd be happy to upvote & accept your comment as the answer if you just copy and pasted.